# Subquery returned more than 1 value not allowed when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

My aim is to take data from one table and update it in another table. I am doing an explicit join and running the query below.

```
UPDATE [Users] set
  name = (
    SELECT concat(Column1,' ',Column2) 
    from [Table2] 
    inner join [Users] on Name = Column3
    where Name like 'ABC'
  )
```

I get the following error when I run the above query:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please note Column1, Column2, Column3 are unique to Table 2, hence I have not added a qualifier.

Comment: How do you want to solve this? Your match condition is returning more than one record, so you need to improve your match criteria to reduce it to a single record.

Comment: I want to update all rows on the column that match the criteria specified with the corresponding values from table 2. How will returning 1 value work?

Comment: You don't currently have a condition which takes into account which row of the update table to update. The provided answer sort of addresses that. But if your query is returning multiple rows, that implies that `Name`/`Column3` isn't unique. Really you need to provide a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UPDATE... JOIN`

```
UPDATE  t1 set
  name = concat(Column1,' ',Column2) 
FROM [Users] t1 JOIN [Table2] on Name = Column3
where Name like 'ABC'
```